# Share files from Google Drive to Dropbox and vice versa

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

I'm working on a app where `Google Drive` and `Dropbox` APIs are integrated but I've an requirement to share a particular file to both the accounts. Instead of uploading to both is there any API to share that file either from Drive to Dropbox or Dropbox to Drive?

Recently I've seen that `Dropbox` has created a [plugin](https://www.dropbox.com/gmail_integration) for `Gmail` which allows user to share the dropbox files link as an attachment.
Also `Gmail` allows the attachment to save to Drive.

Can I do the same with some API, like I share a file link from Dropbox to Drive and Save the linked file to Drive programatically?

I've searched a lot but didn't help. Need some expert advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

APIs that share links do not actually do file copies - it's the browser that is downloading or uploading a file. Consequently those APIs are not sufficient, since what you need is indeed a copy of the file from google  to dropbox or vice versa, or from your location to both of them. What you want to do will require that you do the file transfers.